# Mongodb: How to update $min and $max if value passed is null

Tags: javascript, mongodb, upsert

I have an `upsert` query which relies and a `data` object containing the values. Now, it may so happen that certain fields such as `data.sumPacketSize.value` 
 could be `null`  -  in which case mongo throws an error stating that `$min` / `$max` requires a number value.

My original query is:

```
profiler.upsert({
                    name: target,
                }, {

                    $inc: {
                        flowCount: data.doc_count
                    },
                    $inc: {
                        sumPacketSize: data.sumPacketSize.value
                    },
                    $inc: {
                        sumFlowSize: data.sumFlowSize.value
                    },

                    $max: {
                        maxPacketSize: data.maxPacketSize.value,
                        maxFlowSize: data.maxFlowSize.value
                    },
                    $min: {
                        minPacketSize: data.minPacketSize.value,
                        minFlowSize: data.minFlowSize.value
                    },
                });
```

One approach to solving this is to figure which of the keys of data object have `null` values in them and form a specific mongo query depending on that. However, it isn't elegant and is more so a crude approach.

Another approach would be to first query the db for existing values. If the current value passed is null, then take in the existing values instead:

```
...
...
 let existingProfiler = profiler.findOne({name: target});

 data.maxPacketSize.value === null && existingProfiler && (data.maxPacketSize.value = existingProfiler.maxPacketSize);

data.minFlowSize.value === null && existingProfiler && (data.minFlowSize.value = existingProfiler.minFlowSize);

... no change with the mongo query...
$max: {
       maxPacketSize: data.maxPacketSize.value,
       maxFlowSize: data.maxFlowSize.value               
},
...
...
```

My questions is how can I NOT include the relevant fields in the query if they are null, without having multiple queries for each scenario.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As `$max` and `$min` compares current value with specified value, one solution is to use a dummy value which will force mongo to use current value, i.e.

```
profiler.upsert({
    name: target,
}, {

    $inc: {
        flowCount: data.doc_count
    },
    $inc: {
        sumPacketSize: data.sumPacketSize.value
    },
    $inc: {
        sumFlowSize: data.sumFlowSize.value
    },

    $max: {
        maxPacketSize: data.maxPacketSize.value || SOME_LOWER_BOUND,
        maxFlowSize: data.maxFlowSize.value || SOME_LOWER_BOUND
    },
    $min: {
        minPacketSize: data.minPacketSize.value || SOME_UPPER_BOUND,
        minFlowSize: data.minFlowSize.value || SOME_UPPER_BOUND
    },
});
```